# Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl

Tags: cxf, junit4

I'm running junit on a class that is configured for cxf. I get this error
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
when I ask Spring to retrieve the instance on he class. maven dependency includes cxf 2.7.4  (cxf-rt-ws-policy-2.7.4.jar) and I see neethi 3.0.2.jar is also included. Another post mentioned an issue if neethi 2.x was used with cxf 2.x. but this is not my case.

Comment: See my answer in: [rails-cxf-beancreationexception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777658/grails-cxf-beancreationexception/34177686#34177686)

Comment: I fixed it by rearranging a dependency (with a cxf dependency) and placing it at the end of the dependency section in the pom.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mvn dependency:tree` to find out which dependency also has the `org.apache.neethi:neethi:{version}`. In my case it was the `org.wso2.carbon.core`.
To fix this I added the neethi dependency needed, first in my dependency pom tree.